# Unable to start vsftpd in Debia 8?

Tags: debian, vsftpd, debian-jessie

Ok my boss asked me to install and setup vsftpd in Debian 8.7 but I can not start it with

```
service vsftpd start
```

But I get this error,

```
-bash: service: command not found
```

I tried to apt-get install service but I get,

```
E: Unable to locate package service
```

What is the solution?

Comment: `dpkg-query -S /usr/sbin/service` shows that file belongs to the `sysvinit-utils` package, not a "service" package. Perhaps install that?

Answer (score -1):

Debian 8.0 and up uses systemd, not init. Try `systemctl start vsftpd`

If you want it to start at boot automatically, you'll likely want
`systemctl enable vsftpd`